# How to reset boolean to "default: false" at end of day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, boolean

I have a boolean in the DB: `t.boolean  "completed",      default: false`

I **ONLY** show those still `false` on the home page.

If a user checks one off:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"><% :completed %></span>
```

Completed becomes `true` and it therefore disappears from the home page.

At the end of each day though, how can we automatically reset everything back to `default: false`?

Do I create a model method or scope to do this?

Comment: You can create `rake task` to set `completed` value to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a timestamp instead of a boolean. That has two benefits:

1. You know when the user complated the last time
2. You do not need to reset that value via a cron job at midnight.

The steps would be: First remove the `completed` boolean column from your database and add instead a `completed_at` timestamp column.

Second add two methods to your model that allow the same behaviour than the boolean column before. That means there is not need to change the controller or views:

```
def completed=(boolean)
  self.completed_at = boolean ? Time.current : nil
end

def completed
  completed_at && completed_at >= Time.current.beginning_of_day
end
```

Comment: Hey Spickermann! So do I remove `completed` from the database and if so what would I add to the view in its place, `<% :completed? %>`? Would this mean that if clicked the thing would disappear and then reappear by the beginning of the day tomorrow? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will actually want a rake task to reset them all, then just run it once a day with cron. Have a look at the whenever gem.

You CAN do it without the rake task, but its a bit more difficult and inefficient, you will have to add a completed_timestamp, and set that to the current time whenever it is set to true. Then, whenever you fetch the model, check if the completed_timestamp is before today, and if it is, set it to false before you render your page. You could probably do this in an [after_find](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) callback.

Edit: I highly recommend you go with the cron+rake task solution though, the second method is highly inefficient because you will have to fetch every record and check its timestamp every time you load the page. Its just a terrible solution, but I added it for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `rake task` using [***whenever***](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. Something like below should work

```
every 1.day, :at => '12:00 am' do
  runner "YourModel.method_to_update"
end
```

And in your model, write a method like below

```
def self.method_to_update
  YourModel.update_attribute(completed: false)
end
```