# How to reset timestamp to "nil" at end of day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, timestamp

At the end of each day I intended for this code to reset the timestamp `completed_at` back to `nil`, but it's not working.

```
def completed=(boolean)
  self.completed_at = boolean ? Time.current : nil
end

def completed
  completed_at && completed_at >= Time.current.beginning_of_day
end
```

### What's the point?

The user checks off in the view that he did his habit:

```
<%= link_to ''.html_safe, mark_completed_path(habit), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'update_habit' %>
```

The habit then `fadeOut`'s but the idea is that the habit should return the following day so that everyday the user must check off the habit again.

```
def home
  @habits = current_user.habits.committed_for_today.incomplete.order(:order)
end
```

Comment: what should do this line do. `self.completed_at = boolean ? Time.current : nil`

Comment: what is boolean. do you want to set it to boolean. or nil.?

Comment: I don't quite understand how it works @Athar. This problem arised with the answer presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504575/how-to-reset-boolean-to-default-false-at-end-of-day/31505046?noredirect=1#comment50973965_31505046

Comment: okay the rake task suppose to call a method in your model. which you should write in your model. That will update have this line it. `YourModel.update_attribute(completed: nil)` that way it will update that to nil. have you tried this.?

Comment: @Athar where do I put that line `Habit.update_attribute(completed: nil)`? Do I put it in the controller? I have a method in there that marks `completed_at` for when a habit is checked off, but not a method that resets `completed_at` back to nil. This is the method I have `def mark_completed
    @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    @habit.update(completed_at: Time.now)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render :nothing => true }
      end
  end`

Comment: In the habit model @Athar I have those two methods I listed in the question.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com please re-read the answer in your linked post. The answerer specifically state that you *do not* need to reset the value to nil at midnight, and explains why the timestamp method allows you to omit that.

Comment: so you definitely need a rake task... but first add a method in habit model. ie:  `def reset_habits; Habit.update_attribute(completed_at: nil); end`

Comment: There are two logics in that post. 1) Update the completed to be false at day end through rake task. 2) use completed_at. Now as you have used completed_at logic. simply what cant you just consider those incompleted. whose completed_at is not equal Date.current.?

Comment: @eirikir I reread it and I can't figure how to make it work with my intended goal, which is to make `completed_at` become `nil` again since the home page only lists out `incomplete`. In the habit model we have: `scope :incomplete, -> { where(completed_at: nil) }`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Again, the answerer states that you don't need to do that: "You do not need to reset that value via a cron job at midnight." Then he explains why.

Comment: @eirikir okay so if I'm not making it `nil` what should I change the scope to? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Athar hey `Date.current` doesn't seem to bring my older ones back or `date.today` in the scope. Any other suggestions?

Comment: We need something like `!= Date.today` looking that up. Once I find that I think that might work

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com i didnt get this older ones back part.? change your scope like this  `scope: incompleted, -> {where("created_at < ?",  Date.current)}` wont this help.? and your setter for completed_at will remain the same

Comment: Problem though @Athar. When I click on a habit on the home page now and then reload the page. The habit comes back, which means `completed_at` isn't updating to today's timestamp

Comment: can you please add the mark action of your controller to a question. i think the method you have added above should be renamed from `completed=` to `completed_at=` as there are setter for `completed_at` not completed.

Comment: I added it in the above comments @Athar. And is there a simpler way to write the scope? I want the scope to be everything but `Date.today` I'm confused by what you put there and I think that might be the issue

Comment: this one will return all habits who dont have completed_at to be Date.today `scope: incompleted, -> {where("completed_at != ?", Date.current)}`. everything is fine.. i think it should work now

Comment: Thanks @Athar we got that working :] but another monster lurks. Now when I check off a habit. The one that I check off doesn't get updated, but the habit first in the list does so with the JS the habit I check off correctly disappears, but when I refresh the page the habit first in the list disappears (because like I said it is the one that got updated) and the one that was checked off returns. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84211/discussion-between-athar-and-anthonygalli-com).

Comment: When you get a chance @Athar can you give an answer so I can give you credit :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to set the time to nil at the end of the day, you need to change your scope for incomplete so that it will consider all habits to be incomplete where completed_at is not its current date

if you want all habits, where completed_at is less than the current date. do this

```
 scope: incompleted, -> {where("completed_at is null OR completed_at < ?", Date.current)}
```

This way you dont need any rake task and your logic will be used to consider habits incomplete per day.

Comment: Me again. What about less than & `nil`? Because recently created habits should show on the home page too

Comment: `scope: incompleted, -> {where("completed_at != ?", Date.current)}` doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: output issues or query issues.? there is not syntax issues. if first one is working fine i will remove second one

Comment: perfect.:) updated my answer. i should rather use <> rather than != but still cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Precedence issue, try:

```
   def completed=(boolean)
      self.completed_at = (boolean ? Time.current : nil)
   end
```

Comment: There is no precedence issue here assignment has a lower precedence than the ternary operator [See Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence)